# Footer in Next.js

Tags: css, next.js, footer

EDIT: I'm trying to have the footer at the very end of the page. Right now it won't go there and there is some space at the end of the page

I read about #__next causing problems, and I tried a lot of alternatives; still nothing. I might have done something else wrong, but I can't manage to keep the footer and the very bottom when I expand a page.

[image]

```
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>Covid19 Real Time Data</title>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
          />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

**global.css**

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#__next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

**paper css**

```
.paper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: fit-content;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

**footer component**

```
function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/fabio-catino/">
        Fabio Catino
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
    </Typography>
  );
}

export default function StickyFooter() {
  return (
    <Box
      component="footer"
      sx={{
        py: 3,
        px: 2,
        pd: 3,
        width: '100%',
        // position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: (theme) =>
          theme.palette.mode === 'light'
            ? theme.palette.grey[200]
            : theme.palette.grey[800],
      }}
    >
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <Copyright />
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @FabioC! Can you explain your question more?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't relate your problem with sample code. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I edited the post, but basically I'm trying to get rid of the blank space under the footer and have the footer always at the bottom

Comment: You haven't shared your footer component code...

Comment: @kazim066 my bad. Just added

Comment: you should use `height` instead of `min-height`

Comment: @Joshua changing it to height doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Use element inspector(browser dev tools) to see which height property is applied to #__next and .paper

Comment: @RobLjm They're both set to min-height: 100vh; (I did try to change it to just height or %)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your whole layout but below is what needs to happen for your footer to always be at the bottom of the page or continent whichever is greater.

**`HTML` desired layout - for reference only**

```html
<html> // root
 <body> // body
  <div id="__next"> // default next container
   <header /> // your header
   <main /> // your main content
   <footer /> // your footer
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Since `html` & `body` are handled in `_document` and `#__next` is injected automatically - you only need to set the your content - `header`, `main`, and `footer`.

**__app.{jsx|tsx}**

```js
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
 <> // Fragment shorthand
  <header /> // your header
  <main>
   <Component {...pageProps} />
  </main>
  <footer /> // your footer
 </>
);
```

**Basic styles**

```css
:root, body {
 height:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 width: 100%;
}

#__next {
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}

main {
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

`#__next`, `HTML (:root)`, and `body` need to cover the whole page by setting `height` and `width` to `100%`.

Your contents parent container - `#__next` - must be `flex` so the children can grow or shrink as needed. `flex-direction: column` allows  children to be aligned and grow vertically, .

Next, tell `main` to always fill the white space content with `flex: 1`. Since your header is first, there is no affect on it, however, since your footer is after - this pushes the footer to the bottom of the page.

---

##### Update

This is your raw html layout

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
 <div id="paper">
  <header />
  <main>
   <Component {...pageProps} />
  </main>
  <footer />
  <ScrollTop />
 </div>
);
```

```css
:root, body, #__next { // move next up
 height:100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 width: 100%;
}

#paper {
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}

main {
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

---

[See codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-with-styled-components-forked-8f4ql)

Comment: Hi Sean. Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. My Layout is 

`<HTML>
<head/>
<body>
<div id="__next">
<main>...</main>
</div>
</body>`

Comment: the footer is inside __next div. The header is in Layout.js, so always inside the __next div.

Comment: `<ThemeProvider theme={darkMode}>
      <Paper className={styles.paper}>
        <Navbar onAddTheme={darkModeHandler} />
        <main className={styles.main}>{props.children}</main>
        

        <StickyFooter className={styles.footer}></StickyFooter>
        <ScrollTop {...props}>
          <Fab color="primary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
            <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
          </Fab>
        </ScrollTop>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};`

Comment: I updated the example - make sure you don't have styles overriding these.

Comment: I legit tried to disable the Layout component and make it exactly how you suggested and it's still not working :/ still trying though

Comment: Awesome. Thank you a lot for all the help. Really appreciated it